# The right way to print a collection with delimiter in SmallTalk - Squeak?

Tags: oop, smalltalk, squeak

I have been trying to redefine the printOn method by using this code:

```
coordinates do: [:elem | aStream print: elem] separatedBy: [aStream print: ' ,']
```

where "coordinates" stands for the name of the collection (OrderedCollection), but i was expecting to print this when calling to Transcript show:

```
(2/2) ,(1/1) ,(3/3) ,(-4/4)
```

I got this instead:

```
(2/2)','(1/1)','(3/3)','(-4/4)
```

i. e the quotes was printed as well.

I have tried to play with it, defining a local variable and use it, etc.
Nothing worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `#print:` to print strings. Use `#nextPutAll:` to be safe (works for all collections). `#print:` writes a string representation on the stream and surrounds the argument with quotes, that's why you get quotes in the output.

Comment: aStream << elem and aStream << ' ,' are also shorter.